# difference between Activator.CreateInstance and Activator.CreateInstance<Type>

Tags: c#, createinstance

When writing the following code what is the difference on them:

```
MyClass parcel;
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) parcel = (MyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass));
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) parcel = Activator.CreateInstance<MyClass>();
```

I expected the latter would be much faster because the actual type is already known at compile-time but I do not get any differences. On my machine both work in around 9sec. So what is the difference on them considering the internally used steps?

Comment: its same what i see, but 2nd one is more elegant

Comment: The generic version simply performs the cast for you. This is for convenience.

Comment: That´s bad, I hoped I could gain some seconds using the latter... thanks however

Comment: If you want to speed this up generate a Func<T> using expression trees that instantiates the type for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At simplest take a look at the source code.

The [`Activator.CreateInstance(type)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/activator.cs,4c7b92371a93f246) calls [`Activator.CreateInstance(type, false);`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/activator.cs,b4bd78f6527c2e40) which is implemented as this (shortened version):

```
RuntimeType rt = type.UnderlyingSystemType as RuntimeType;
StackCrawlMark stackMark = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;

return rt.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(!nonPublic, false, true, ref stackMark);
```

The [generic version](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/activator.cs,168fafb64ad2a01e) is implemented (also shortened) as:

```
RuntimeType rt = typeof(T) as RuntimeType;
StackCrawlMark stackMark = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;

return (T)rt.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(true, true, true, ref stackMark);
```

So the only difference is the second boolean parameter, which has the argument name `skipCheckThis`, which does some [minor internal tests or not](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/rttype.cs,215ffab257115f14). Due to this the generic version is slightly faster cause it simply skips these tests, but you won't be really able to measure these differences.